# RJSONIO in Linux environment errors out with https

Tags: r, rscript

Hi I'm using RJSONIO in Windows and when I perform the following it works fine:

```
library(RJSONIO)    
fromJSON("https://issues.apache.org/jira/rest/api/2/project")
```

It returns a JSON but when I do the same thing in Linux I get the following error:

```
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
```

after doing some search on Google I noticed I needed to mention "file="
    fromJSON(file="https://issues.apache.org/jira/rest/api/2/project")

so now I get the error:

```
unable to find an inherited method for function âfromJSONâ for signature â"missing", "missing"â
```

Any suggests ?

Comment: What versions are you using on both machines? You can do `installed.packages()["RJSONIO", "Version"]` to find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is explained in `?url`: `http://` URLs work exactly like files everywhere,
but `https://` URLs do not.

> Note that the `https://` URL scheme is not supported except on 
>   Windows. There it is only supported if `--internet2` or
>   `setInternet2(TRUE)` was used  (to make use of Internet Explorer
>   internals), and then only if the certificate is considered to be
>   valid.  With that option only, the `http://user:pass@site` notation
>   for sites requiring authentication is also accepted.

You can explicitly use `RCurl`:

```
fromJSON(RCurl::getURL("https://issues.apache.org/jira/rest/api/2/project"))
```